# How to handle multiple clients using single twilio Number? what happen if some one dial twilio number which is used by multiple clients?

Tags: android, twilio, android-pendingintent

I am working on calling app using Twilio API, I have done outgoing call which is working but for incoming call I am getting a twilio message but it not divert to number so that I can communicate with other. I am using single number but there are multiple clients 
for example 
 A and B are clients for number +1XXXXXXXXX, 
 what happen 
if someone called to the number +1XXXXXXXXX, where it will divert either A side or B side.
when I tried to call using my phone, its giving only welcome message and then single ring comes and its not diverting to another. Can any one please suggest me whats wrong going?

Comment: Hey there, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio. It is absolutely possible to have multiple clients using the same number. I can't tell what's going wrong right now though. Can you share the TwiML you're using to divert to the clients, or any of your code? Thanks.

Comment: @philnash, now  the issue is resolved, I am able to call client to client. I had gone through twilio quick start, but I have only doubt that if some-one did call on twilio number then where will be the call get diverted, in other words which client will get call.

Comment: Which client gets the call is down to what your code does. The call will come in and request the TwiML from your application. I would suggest writing code that queries to find any clients that aren't currently busy and route to one of them with the TwiML. If all clients are busy, you can start to build a queue with the `<Queue>` verb. Feel free to drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com if you have more in depth questions.